# How to install vamp library in Python. (Windows 64b)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't install vamp library. PyСharm / Windows 11 (64 bit) / Python 3.8-3.9-3.10
Tried to change the interpreter version from 3.8 to 3.10
The full version of Microsoft C++ Build Tools is installed.
The required libraries are installed (incl wheel and numpy)

All the time I get an error:

```
Collecting vamp
  Using cached vamp-1.1.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: vamp
  Building wheel for vamp (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for vamp (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for vamp
Failed to build vamp
Installing collected packages: vamp
  Running setup.py install for vamp: started
  Running setup.py install for vamp: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
...

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

vamp

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried downloading the vamp plugins pack from the official site https://www.vamp-plugins.org/download.html but their file links are broken.

I also found their repository on github (https://github.com/sonic-visualiser/vamp-plugin-pack), but I can’t figure out how to compile it into a library for Windows 11 (64) for Python

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install python 2.7. After that, you pip install vamp